# What is a suitable loss function and evaluation metric for a classification model with large number of unbalanced target classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining, multiclass-classification, nlp

I am building a multiclass classifier to predict the "Intent" of a question.
There are some 100 classes in the target variable and each target class contains an unequal proportion of observations/questions varying from 3 % to 40 %.

**Questions**

1. What would be a good evaluation metric for this classifier?
2. What is the best proxy loss function for optimizing the suggested evaluation metric?

EDIT: This is not a ranking problem. The model should predict only 1 target class.
The cost of misclassification is the same for each target class.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at `sensitivity` and `specificity`. They can be combined effectively to either provide a basis for a correct classification, or the basis for an exclusionary classification within each class.  That said, if you are looking for a measure for the model as a whole, you'll probably want to look at some sort of weighted average of the `sensitivity` scores.

`sensitivity` is the same calculation as `precision`, but `specificity` is not the same as `recall`.

That said, you may need to have several models that specialize in different areas or, perhaps as worst case scenario, you may need to produce a one-vs-the-rest ensemble of models to get the best results. This might help if, as **anymous.asker** suggested, perhaps you can introduce some cost around positive or negative outcomes.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Usually ranking metrics such as precision at N (e.g. how many times the real class is within the top-3 or top-5 predicted by the model). If you can somehow incorporate similarity information or a cost for each missclassification type, there are other metrics that might be more appropriate.

Comment: This is not a ranking problem. The model should predict only 1 target class. The cost is same for each missclassification

Answer (score 0):

You can use some related parameters as cost function such as Kappa, CEN, and MCEN in all types of algorithms.

Disclaimer:

If you are using Python you can use [PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) module. This module after receiving the confusion matrix of your data can suggest some parameters which is suitable for evaluating your algorithm according to the characteristics of your dataset.

Here is a simple code to get the recommended parameters from this module:

```
>>> from pycm import *

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(matrix={"Class1": {"Class1": 1, "Class2":2}, "Class2": {"Class1": 0, "Class2": 5}})  

>>> print(cm.recommended_list)
["Kappa", "SOA1(Landis & Koch)", "SOA2(Fleiss)", "SOA3(Altman)", "SOA4(Cicchetti)", "CEN", "MCEN", "MCC", "J", "Overall J", "Overall MCC", "Overall CEN", "Overall MCEN", "AUC", "AUCI", "G", "DP", "DPI", "GI"]
```

After that, each of this parameter you want to use as the loss function can be used as following:

```
>>> y_pred = model.predict      #the prediction of the implemented model

>>> y_actu = data.target        #data labels

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred)

>>> loss = cm.Kappa             #or any other parameter (Example: cm.SOA1)
```